# Entity Framework - force using group by

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to force Entity Framework to use group by in generated SQL statement, here's my query in C#:

```
result = from g in entries.GroupBy(i => new { i.CustomerCompanyId, i.CurrencyId })
         join customerCompany in dataContext.CustomerCompanies on g.Key.CustomerCompanyId equals customerCompany.CustomerCompanyId
         join customer in dataContext.Customers on customerCompany.CustomerId equals customer.CustomerId
         join currency in dataContext.Currencies on g.Key.CurrencyId equals currency.CurrencyId
         select new Progress
         {
             Field1 = g.Sum(i => i.Field1),
             Field2 = g.Sum(i => i.Field2),
             CurrencyId = g.Key.CurrencyId,
             CurrencyName = currency.Name,
             CurrencySymbol = currency.Symbol,
             CustomerCompanyId = g.Key.CustomerCompanyId,
             Field3 = g.Sum(i => i.Field3),
             Field4 = g.Sum(i => i.Field4),
             Field5 = g.Sum(i => i.Field5),
        };
```

What EF translates into SQL is a query with many sub-queries and each of it  contains one sum statement translated into inner select (I am not pasting it here as it would fill entire screen), but what I am trying to achieve (and which has good performance according to benchmarks is:

```
SELECT sub.*, C.CustomerName, CUR.Name FROM
  (SELECT
    SUM(Field1),
    SUM(Field2),
    ...,
    CustomerCompanyId,
    CurrencyId
  GROUP BY
    CustomerCompanyId, CurrencyId) AS sub
JOIN CustomerCompany CC ON CC.CustomerCompanyId = sub.CustomerCompanyId
JOIN Customer C ON C.CustomerId = CC.CustomerId
JOIN Customer CUR ON CUR.CurrencyId = sub.CustomerId
```

There must be a way how to force EF generate it (I know that writing custom SP is an option too, but this is not my primary way).

Comment: ORMs are NOT meant for reporting queries. Write a view that perform the reporting query you want and map your objects (I won't say entities) to it. If you need to pass a parameter to a subquery, use a function

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks I was affraid of it as it means extra effort

Comment: BTW your LINQ query specifically asks for `GROUP BY` subqueries in the `Select` statement itself. LINQ isn't magic, it won't try to refactor the query. *Humans* can't refactor such queries. To avoid performing multiple aggregations you need to rewrite the entire query

Comment: you need to pay extra effort anyway. The query is wrong. If you want to use the sums of `Field1`, `Field2` etc you need to *select* them before joining to other tables. It's the same thing you'd do in SQL - you'd write a subquery or a CTE that returned `CompanyID,CurrencyID` and the totals before joining to the other tables